# How to type in norm (latex) in ipython notebook (Jupyter)?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex

How to markdown norm (L2 Euclidean distance) in ipython notebook (Jupyter)

```
$ norm... $
```

Comment: This is not really related to jupyter is it? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107186/how-to-write-norm-which-adjusts-its-size

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the norm of x you can write the following:

```
$$ \lVert x \rVert $$
```